# Macros for Auto filter, Auto Copy and then Auto paste in separate sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have the data of the following type in excel:

Year|Trade Flow|Partner|Commodity Code|Commodity|Qty Unit|Qty|Netweight (kg)|Trade Value (US$)

In the year column it ranges from 1990 to 2014. I need to develop a macro code such that it can filter the values based on year individually and then paste it in different sheets of the same excel file.

Any help in this regard,. would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.  We can help you down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the rows. Each time you hit a new year, insert a sheet for that year and copy the rows to it.

This assumes your data is on sheet1 and you don't have sheets named 1990, 1991, 1992, etc.

This also assumes that your data is sorted by ColumnA(Year).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim strValue As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim jRow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = 1
    jRow = 1

    ws.Activate
    'Loop through and copy the records to the new sheet.
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        'If this is a new year, create a sheet for it.
        If ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value <> strValue Then
            strValue = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value
            Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count)).name = strValue
            jRow = 1
        End If

        ws.Rows(lRow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(strValue).Range("A" & jRow)

        jRow = jRow + 1
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```